# How to create timeline with right sign icons above it and it fills out after completing the step

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm creating the circles connected to each other in one line(timeline), also I want to create the right sign icon above them and they must fill after completing each step.

```
CSS

li {
 width: 2em;
 height: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 2em;
 border-radius: 1em;
 background: dodgerblue;
 margin: 0 1em;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
}

li::before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: .9em;
left: -4em;
width: 4em;
height: .2em;
background: dodgerblue;
z-index: -1;
}


li:first-child::before {
display: none;
}

.active {
background: dodgerblue;
}

.active ~ li {
background: lightblue;
}
```

Html

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="active">4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
</ul>
```

I've attached the file as I want to create the design
[Right Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uhm8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am advising to use font awesome to make right sign icon. Font awesome is CSS lightweight icon library

```
<i class="fas fa-right" id="righticon" style="display:none;"></i>
```

This is the way to use font awesome and can also use javascript to enable the right signs when they completed.First you have to disable the right icon and enable when they completed here is the javascript code.

```
var rightsign = document.getElementById("righticon").style.display="block";
```

Here it completed..Thanks